# EDI Delta - How to condition on UoM

Tags: edi, delta

I need to ONLY process 856 data for line items that have an MEA segment with MEA02 = 'LF'

There are a number of MEA segments for each HL Package Loop.

Comment: The user group is probably a better place for this question.  SO is good for programming / architecture questions.  Specific software applications like Delta probably won't have much of an audience here.

Comment: I'll post it there Monday.  Thanks so much!!